# The Hilbert Symbol and real algebraic geometry

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $(a,b)_K$ be the quadratic Hilbert symbol in a local field $K$. Let $a$ be a rational number.  By a consequence of the quadratic reciprocity law we have:
$$\prod_{p} (a,-1)_{\mathbb{Q}_p}=\mathrm{sgn}(a),$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}(a)$ is the sign of $a$. My question is if this formula can be generalized to a totally real number field.

Comment: For a number field $K$, consider the quaternion algebra $Q$ generated by $a,b\in (K^\times)\setminus (K^\times)^2$.  This gives a $2$-torsion element in the Brauer group of $K$.  There is a reciprocity short exact sequence $0\to \text{Br}(K) \to \bigoplus_v \text{Br}(K_v) \xrightarrow{\text{inv}} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ where the middle term is the "restricted product" over all places $v$ of the Brauer group of the completed field.  Thus, the sum over all real embeddings of $(-1)^{\text{sign}(ab)}$ equals the sum of invariants of $Q$ at non-Archimedean places.

Comment: Typo correction: "$(-1)^{\text{sign}(ab)}$" should be $\overline{0}\in (\mathbb{Z}(1/2))/\mathbb{Z}$ if the sign is $+1$ and $\overline{1/2}$ if the sign is $-1$.

Comment: It is not clear how your question is related to real algebraic geometry. Unless you explain this, please modify the title accordingly.

Comment: The relationship with real algebraic geometry is that in $\mathbb{Q}$ the positive conus of the elements in the form $a=X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2$ is exactly those such that $\prod_p (a,-1)_p=1$, my question is if it can be generalizated.